# Calculate index in array from XYZ?

Tags: c#, arrays, opengl, 3d, buffer

I need some help coming up with the proper algorithm to fill a vertex float buffer array with data...

Since each vertex has 9 attributes (XYZ,UV,RGBA) in my setup, and I am drawing with quads, each face has a total of 36 indices. I am drawing cubes so that's 6 faces for a total of 216 (9 * 4 * 6) indices. Instead of just iterating the buffer to fill it by the following:

```
public void AddVertex(int x, int y, int z, float u, float v, Color4 color)
    {
        if (vCount >= vertex_data.Length)
            return;
        else
        {
            vertex_data[vCount++] = x;
            vertex_data[vCount++] = y;
            vertex_data[vCount++] = z;
            vertex_data[vCount++] = u;
            vertex_data[vCount++] = v;
            vertex_data[vCount++] = color.R;
            vertex_data[vCount++] = color.G;
            vertex_data[vCount++] = color.B;
            vertex_data[vCount++] = color.A;
        }
    }
```

I want to use an offset to directly target the position in the buffer to be updated on the GPU (by use of BufferSubData). However, the problem is translating the relative position value of a cube (XYZ) into the position in the buffer array so I can update it's values.

This is how I am iterating cubes, and my attempt at getting the correct position...

```
for (int x = 0; x < Chunk.DEFAULT_SIZE; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Chunk.DEFAULT_SIZE; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < Chunk.DEFAULT_SIZE; z++)
                {
                    <...>
                    offset = (x + size * (y + size * z)) * 216;
                    SetVertex(offset, face_i.X + absX, face_i.Y + absY, face_i.Z + -absZ, u, v, color);
                    //SetVertex (...) would be called 3 more times, and "offset" would be supplemented by 0,9,18, and 27 (totalling 36 indices).
                    <...>
                }
            }
        }
```

I even tried bit-shifting the XYZ values:

```
int offset = 216 * (x<<10) + 216 * (y<<5) + 216*z;
```

That only worked in certain situations. Am I going about this the wrong way or? The result of above code creates only the bottom face of the cubes, but it does create them at all the correct intervals.

Comment: Shouldn't  `216` in this code: `offset = (x + size * (y + size * z)) * 216;` be replaced with whatever the current index count is? I.e., when `x=y=z=0`, shouldn't that `216` number be `0` instead? Also what's with all the parentheses in `SetVertex(offset, face_i.X + absX), face_i.Y + absY), face_i.Z + -absZ), u, v, color);`, there's one opening and four closing parentheses.

Comment: Whoops,  typo that I missed while i simplified it. Thx - correcting now.

Comment: Yes, normally it would be offset + i . i being 9 * (x<4). Editing question to include that.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding your second code block. What do `x`, `y`, and `z` represent in your second code block? If they are the position of a cube as you say, then if `Chunk.DEFAULT_SIZE` is say, `1`, then your code should draw a single cube, right? In which case you need to call `SetVertex` 36 times, not 4 as your code comment says (6 faces with 4 vertices each = `SetVertex` called 36 times). That would explain why you are only getting one face.

Comment: Uh, I meant 24 times, 6*4=24, I'm sure you get the idea though. Ignore my original comment, I thought x,y,z were each vertex, but with it being each cube then the 216 number makes sense. Currently you are only drawing 1/6th of a cube though and have only defined 9*4=36 vertices, not 216 (until you add the 5 other faces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is write code that gives you the offset of the address of the vertex you want to modify, given a coordinate, a face, and a vertex. This will save you a lot of headaches when addressing data pointers. This would probably look something like this:

```
size_t get_offset(int x, int y, int z, face_enum face, vertex_enum vertex) {
    size_t x_offset = x * Chunk.DEFAULT_SIZE * Chunk.DEFAULT_SIZE;
    size_t y_offset = y * Chunk.DEFAULT_SIZE;
    size_t z_offset = z;

    size_t cube_offset = x_offset + y_offset + z_offset;

    size_t face_offset = convert_face_enum_to_index(face); //I'm here assuming that all the possible enums map to indexes in the range [0,5]

    size_t quad_offset = cube_offset * 6 + face_offset; //Multiplied by six for six faces

    size_t vertex_offset = convert_vertex_enum_to_index(vertex); //I'm here assuming that all the possible enums map to indexes in the range [0,3]

    size_t vertex_location = quad_offset * 4 + vertex_offset; //Multiplied by four for four vertices per quad.
    const size_t num_of_floats_per_vertex = 9; //Based on your problem description, this should be correct

    return vertex_location * num_of_floats_per_vertex;
}

public void modify_vertex(float * location, float x, float y, float z, float u, float v, Color4 color) {
    location[0] = x;
    location[1] = y;
    location[2] = z;
    location[3] = u;
    location[4] = v;
    location[5] = color.R;
    location[6] = color.G;
    location[7] = color.B;
    location[8] = color.A;
}
```

If all attempts to add or modify vertex data is done in this fashion, it'll make your life much simpler. Once you've done this, you can then write code that looks like this:

```
for(cube qube : cubes) { //Depends on your implementation. If you've literally stored all the cubes in a cube[][][] array, then the triple-nested code you wrote above would be adequate.
    for(face_enum face = FACE0; face <= FACE5; face++) { //I'm assuming that face_enum has an increment operator; this may need to be adjusted depending on what you write.
        for(vertex_enum vertex = VERTEX0; vertex <= VERTEX3; vertex++) { //same deal here.
            size_t vertex_offset = get_offset(qube.x, qube.y, qube.z, face, vertex);
            float * data_offset = my_mapped_vertex_buffer + vertex_offset;
            modify_vertex(data_offset, /*insert appropriate data here*/);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, as long as you set up your vertex buffer object (and all the associated attribute pointers) correctly, this will store all the relevant rendering data in a consistent and easy-to-modify (from a programmer's perspective) manner.

Of course, you do have to make sure that the vertex buffer is large enough to store every cube, but that was still a problem with the old code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Few questions...
- "convert_vertex_enum_to_index(vertex)", do you mean literally which face 0-5?
- "float * data_offset = my_mapped_vertex_buffer + vertex_offset;", what is "my_mapped_vertex_buffer "? the buffer float array?

Comment: @ChrisGlenn `my_mapped_vertex_buffer` is basically a shorthand for whatever storage medium you're using to maintain the vertex data. Whether it's saved on the heap in a `std::vector` or whether you're mapping it from the graphics card, it doesn't really matter. `convert_vertex_enum_to_index` is the same thing: it's a shorthand for "which vertex am I addressing, the first, the second, the third, or the fourth?" converted into "first == 0, second == 1, third == 2, and fourth == 3".

Comment: Right. Making sure we are on the same page :)

So, I adapted your code to mine, however, it's rendering only the bottom faces of each cube now. I'm not sure why it's updating only a single face per cube though...

Here's the full code:: http://pastebin.com/ANLnVvmc